# Trying to parse spotify response string into json object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, spotify

I've been using spotify api lately using ajax in browser and I haven't got any problem so far. But now I'm trying to use it with node.js, I'm just doing a simple get and trying to parse the string into JSON object but i get a syntax error in return. Here is the code:

```
var https = require('https')

var dir = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=tania+bowra&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist"
https.get(dir, function (response){
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (data){
        var str = data;
        var jObj = JSON.parse(str);
        console.log(jObj);
    })
})
```

This is what I receive as response and want to parse it into Json object:

```
{
    "artists": {
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=tania+bowra&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist",
        "items": [
            {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q"
                },
                "followers": {
                    "href": null,
                    "total": 21
                },
                "genres": [],
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q",
                "id": "08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "height": 640,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/f2798ddab0c7b76dc2d270b65c4f67ddef7f6718",
                        "width": 640
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 300,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/b414091165ea0f4172089c2fc67bb35aa37cfc55",
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 64,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8522fc78be4bf4e83fea8e67bb742e7d3dfe21b4",
                        "width": 64
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Tania Bowra",
                "popularity": 4,
                "type": "artist",
                "uri": "spotify:artist:08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q"
            }
        ],
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

And this is the error i get:

```
undefined:16


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\path:12:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:373:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:750:26)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:730:3)
    at _stream_readable.js:717:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

The same petition in browser works perfectly and there is no error aparently in Json format as I checked in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You're parsing the string too early. You should instead be parsing after you're done aggregating all of the data chunks into a single string. The data callback gets executed multiple times, as chunks of data are received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'data' callback function will be called with each chunk of data received so you have to collect all the data and then parse it:

```
https.get(dir, function (response){
  var str = '';
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (data){
    str += data;
  });
  response.on('end', function (){
    var jObj = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(jObj);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Still newbie at how callbacks works